# Channel Entries Related Entries Filtering with Count

Tags: channel-entries

Lets say I have Channel A and B.

Channel A has a Field X which is a relationship to channel B.

Is there a way for the {exp:channel:entries} tag to get

1. only those Channel B entries that are referred by current entries in Channel A?
2. the number of entries in Channel A that are associated to each respective Channel B entries?

For example:

If Channel A has these entries

```
Entry 1, Relationship to Channel B entry 1
Entry 2, Relationship to Channel B entry 1
Entry 3, Relationship to Channel B entry 2
```

and Channel B has these entries

```
Entry 1, Foo
Entry 2, Bar
Entry 3, Test
```

then

No. 1 should return

```
Entry 1, Foo
Entry 2, Bar
```

No. 2 should return

```
Entry 1, Foo, Referred 2 times
Entry 2, Bar, Referred 1 time
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Playa's Parent & Children tags](http://pixelandtonic.com/playa/docs/templates) should do what you're looking for. They have documentation on [converting a native Relationship field to a Playa field](http://pixelandtonic.com/playa/docs/conversion).